# SSRS 2012, linear trendline in line chart

Tags: reporting-services, linechart, trendline

I 'm trying to add Linear Trendline to a line chart in SSRS, but there is no separate option for trendline in AddCalculatedSeries. Most of the solutions found on tech forums say, trendline should be calculated in SQL. Is there any way out to do this in SSRS tool or do I have to go through SQL coding to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible inside SSRS so you have to do it inside your SQL query. Here is a good example that might help you or anyone else who stumbles upon this problem:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3432/add-a-linear-trendline-to-a-graph-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Answer (score -2):

Is "Moving average" not what you are looking for?

(Add Calculated Series -> Moving Average)

Comment: He was asking for linear trendline